# Can't figure out how to remove widgets and then add new ones in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label

So, I'm using tkinter for a program where the user must log in using entry fields and labels:

Code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()


def all_children(window):
    _list = window.winfo_children()
    for item in _list:
        if item.winfo_children():
            _list.extend(item.winfo_children())
    return _list

def rules():
    clear()
    ruleLabel = tk.Label(master, textvariable="Test")
    ruleLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
    master.update()

def clear():
    widget_list = all_children(master)
    for item in widget_list:
        item.grid_forget()
        master.update()
    master.update()

def login():
    tk.Label(master, text="Username").grid(row=0)
    tk.Label(master, text="Password").grid(row=1)

    global entry1
    entry1 = tk.Entry(master)
    global entry2
    entry2 = tk.Entry(master)

    entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    tk.Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)
    tk.Button(master, text='Enter', command=lambda: rules()).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)


login()
master.mainloop()
```

When I run it clears the first set of widgets correctly but then never adds the new label, am I doing something wrong?

FYI I'm quite new to Tkinter so it may be obvious.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `item.destroy()` ?

Comment: Please create a complete [mcve]. It's impossible for us to know what "Then:" means. We need to see how and when those lines of code are being called.

Comment: I have made the minimal reproducible example, sorry for the first version I was in a rush as I couldn't figure out the issue so wanted to make the post ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is created but its content is empty.

Change the below line inside `rules()`:

```
ruleLabel = tk.Label(master, textvariable="Test")
```

to

```
ruleLabel = tk.Label(master, text="Test")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly now, I knew it would be a small mistake.

Comment: If it solves your question, you are appreciated to accept it as an answer by clicking the tick beside the answer.